# Is it possible to create a mapping class in Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-core

In previous versions of Entity Framework we could use `EntityTypeConfiguration<TEntity>` to configure the mapping for the entity of type `TEntity` on the constructor.

The other option is to set the mapping on the `OnModelCreating` method of the `DbContext`, but this other option is nice because we can leave each mapping in its own place.

Now I'm starting to use Entity Framework Core and I could not find the `EntityTypeConfiguration<TEntity>` class, so I believe things have changed.

Is it possible to create a mapping class in the new version of Entity Framework or for now we have to use the `OnModelCreating`?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `OnModelCreating` is the preferred way to do it right now. The team (specifically rowanmiller) mentioned that:

> I think we will probably do this, or something like it, but it is lower priority than some of the other features EF Core is missing at the moment.

https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/2805

If you read through the comments on that issue, there are some alternative ways to do it, but not "officially" supported ways other than `OnModelCreating` right now.